# Using interp1 for non-uniform query points

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I'd like to use the `interp1` function to (linearly) interpolate between sample points. For uniform interpolation between sample points, I can use

```
test = [-1 -2 0 3];
new = interp1(test,1:.5:numel(test));
```

which will give an interpolated series, where the new series now includes one additional interpolated point between each of the original (`test`) series points.

What I would like to do is, create a `new` series that interpolates depending upon the differences between `test` series points. For the case above, the resulting output would look like

```
[-1 -2 -1 0 1 2 3];
```

I've worked through the examples at http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html, but the answer still eludes me. I'd appreciate a little direction for this simple query.

Comment: Isn't that simply `min(test):max(test)`?

Comment: @LuisMendo omg, you are right of course. Have look at my complicated answer for this :( Of course that is only right for linear interpolation, while the `interp1` solution can use any interpolation method, e.g. cubic

Comment: @hbaderts It's not really clear what the OP wants. Perhaps they should clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general syntax for `interp1` is

```
vq = interp1(x,v,xq);
```

where `x` and `v` are the input and `xq` and `vq` are the interpolated vectors. You are using the shorter syntax

```
vq = interp1(v,xq);
```

where `x` is assumed to be `1:length(v)`.

In my opinion, it is easier to create an `x` vector which allows you to interpolate with `xq=1:length(vq)`, than to make `x=1:length(v)` and calculate `xq`. To construct the correct `x` vector, you can do the following:

1. Use `diff(test)` to find the difference between the `v` values. This tells you how many interpolated values you need inbetween.
2. We'll want to use absolute differences: `abs(diff(test))`.
3. To get the corresponding `x` values, we can do a `cumsum` on this result, starting at `1`. That is: `cumsum([1, abs(diff(test))]);`. For the `test` input, this gives us: `[1  2  4  7]` which seems right: no additional value between `-1` and `-2`, one value between `-2` and `0`, and finally two values between `0` and `3`.

We can use this vector as `x` and then get the vector `xq` as all elements from 1 to the maximum value in `x`:

```
x = cumsum([1, abs(diff(test))]);
xq = 1:max(x);
```

Then we can do the interpolation:

```
vq = interp1(x,test,xq);
```

which gives us

```
vq = 
   -1   -2   -1    0    1    2    3
```

Comment: This is a really nice overview of the `interp1` function. Working through this answer cleared up a couple of issues I had with implementation, including the example I provided. Appreciate the effort.